# how to set up this association and model migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, associations

I have users, posts, and comments. Posts belong to users. Users have many posts.

Now where I'm confused is that users are supposed to be able to comment on others' posts.
How do I set up this association?

Should I write users have many comments, posts have many comments, comments belong to posts and users? or user has many comments through posts?
Also what columns should the model table have? Does it need user_id, post_id, content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct the first time.

Users have many comments. Posts have many comments. Comment belongs to User. Comment belongs to Post.

The comments table should have user_id and post_id.

So `user.comments` will be comments that a user has made. `post.comments` will be comments on that post.

This is an association to say "This user commented on this post."

Answer (score 1):

use [has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

**User model:**

```
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, :through => :posts
```

**Post model:**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
```

**Comment model:**

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: What exactly is using the :through going to do? in this case I won't need the user_id column?

Comment: to find which user commented on which post, you need both user_id and post_id columns in comments table.